# How to feed sequences of 2D data into Keras Sequential LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to predict sequences of 2D coordinates in a grid map. To do that I have a training set `Input_train` with the shape `(41185, 10, 2)`, so I have 41185 examples of sequences, which are 10 timesteps long and each step cointains 2 coordinates.

This is my model:

```
self.model = Sequential()
                self.model.add(LSTM(self.num_neurons, input_shape=(10, 2), dropout=self.dropout, recurrent_dropout=self.dropout,
                         return_sequences=True))
                for _ in range(self.depth - 1):
                    self.model.add(
                        LSTM(self.num_neurons, dropout=self.dropout, recurrent_dropout=self.dropout,
                             return_sequences=True))
                self.model.add(
                    LSTM(self.num_neurons, dropout=self.dropout, recurrent_dropout=self.dropout))
                self.model.add(Dense(units=3802, activation='relu'))
                self.model.compile(loss=self._get_loss(), optimizer=self._build_optimizer())
```

The output of my network should be a 3802 x 3802 array, where the future coordinates are marked with a 1 in the corresponding entry.

The calls:

```
model.summary()
print "Inputs: {}".format(model.input_shape)
print "Outputs: {}".format(model.output_shape)
print "Actual input: {}".format(Input_train.shape)
print "Actual output: {}".format(Labels_train[0].shape)
```

yield:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, None, 258)         269352    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, None, 258)         533544    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 258)               533544    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3802)              984718    
=================================================================
Total params: 2,321,158
Trainable params: 2,321,158
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Inputs: (None, 10, 2)
Outputs: (None, 3802)
Actual input: (41185, 10, 2)
Actual output: (3802, 3802)
```

But after i call:

```
history = self.model.fit(Input_train, Labels_train, shuffle=True, validation_data=(Input_test, Labels_test),
                                     verbose=self.verbose)
```

The following error occurs:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 41185 arrays: [array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0....
```

Whats my error here?

Answer (score 0):

convert each 2D array into 1D and then try to feed it to LSTM and while retrieving it convert it back to 2D.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Just append each row after another.
ex: INPUT --> [[1,2,3],[0,9,8]]
CONVERT --> [1,2,3,0,9,8]

Comment: if I reshape `Input_train.reshape(len(Input_train), 20)` then I get the shape `(41185, 20)` but when I try to feed it into the network the error is `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (41185, 20)`